# Accessing localhost of GCP instance from local machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, network-programming

I am trying to run my flask app on GCP instance. However the app gets published at local host of that instance. I want to access that instances localhost.

I saw couple of videos and article but almost all were about deploying app on GCP. Is there no simple way to just forward whatever is published on localhost of VM instance to my PC browser and If I submit some information in the app then it goes to VM instance and gives back the result to my local machine's browser via VM instances localhost.

Comment: Neo Andersons's answer is good. However, do you understand what `localhost` means? You can configure your app to listen to connections and not require forwarding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: @JohnHanley are you telling that in my flask app if I configure `host` as my local laptop ip address will it publish in my browser ?

Comment: Yes, you can make your app public. 1) Assign a public IP address to the VM instance. 2) Change from `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` in your app. 3) In the Google Cloud Firewall, enable the port your app is listening on. 4) Now you can access your app using the public IP address in your browser.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Local Port Forwarding` when you `ssh` into the target instance hosted in GCP.

`Local port forwarding` lets you connect from your local machine to another server. To use local port forwarding, you need to know your destination server, source port and target port.

You should already know your destination server. The target port must be the one on which your flask app is listening. The source port can be any port that is not in use on your local computer.

Assuming flask app is listening on port `8080` on the GCP instance and you want to make the app available in your local computer on port `9876`, ssh into your GCP instance using the following command:

```
ssh -L 9876:127.0.0.1:8080 <username>@<gcpInstanceIP>
```

---

Same result can be achieved using `gcloud compute ssh` if you don't have the ssh key on the target instance.
The `--` argument must be specified between gcloud specific args on the left and SSH_ARGS on the right:

```
gcloud compute ssh <gcp-instance-name> --zone=<instance-zone> -- -L <source-port>:localhost:<target-port>
```

---

You can also use the Google Cloud Shell:

- <kbd>Activate Cloud Shell</kbd> located at the top-right corner in the GCP Web Interface
- ssh into your instance with `Local Port Forwarding`

```
gcloud compute ssh <gcp-instance-name> --zone=<instance-zone> -- -L 8080:localhost:<target-port>
```

- Click the <kbd>Web Preview</kbd> in the `Google Cloud Shell`, the <kbd>Preview on port</kbd> `8080`.
  [image]

Comment: Hi I tried the first command but I got this error 
`Permission denied (publickey)` . Do I have to set any public private key pair using the Putty key generator ?

Comment: I assume you are trying to connect from a Windows machine. Here is a guide: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#windows . The public key must also be added on the instance. I personally use the second and third option that I suggested when I am working on a Windows machine. It should be more straight forward for you as well. Good Luck

Comment: Third option should work on the spot(2 minutes), on the second option you need to install the gcloud cli and configure your credentials, while if you choose the first option, you need to generate the key, manage it in putty or other ssh client, send the *.pub on the instance, make sure ingress:22 from your IP is allowed etc. Good Luck